# Best programable chess game on the market

Tags: software, programming, famous-games

I would like to program famous chess matches into a chess program so I can watch the matches. Is there a chess program that allows this or is there already a program that has famous chess matches we can watch?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you want to watch famous chess games, a simple online chess database such as chessgames.com should provide you with everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

More or less every chess program is able to load games, replay them and even  sometimes analyze them. Personally I use [SCID](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) for replaying PGN games. It is free and works very well.